# LARAVEL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I've tried to create an admin module for a schoolproject with laravel.
I copied all the authentication stuff to register a person, but changed everything so it's a a different module. However, I can't seem to fix this problem. It always says that my 'created_at' doesn't have a default value. But it has the timestamp() module so I would think that it doesn't need anything else. Anyone who sees the fault.

My Migration:

```
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('admin_id');
            $table->string('naam');
            $table->string('email')->unique;
            $table->binary('password');
            $table->enum('rol', ['user','admin'])->default('admin');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
};
```

My model

```
class Admin extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected  $table = 'admins';

    protected $primaryKey = 'admin_id';

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'admin_id',
        'naam',
        'email',
        'password',
        'rol',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

My Controller

```
class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', 'min:5'],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }


    public function createAdmin()
    {
        return view('auth.registeradmin');
    }


    public function storeAdmin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'naam' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', 'min:5'],
        ]);

        $admin = Admin::create([
            'naam' => $request->naam,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($admin));

        Auth::login($admin);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you even bothering including `nullable` timestamps? Just use the `$table->timestamps()` method, and set `public $timestamps = true;` on your Model; `created_at` and `updated_at` will then be filled in by the system. I can't speak to _why_ your code is currently throwing that error, but your approach seems off...

Comment: Oh wait, yes I do. `$user = User::create([`; that's the wrong Model/Table. You have `admins` and an `Admin` model, so why are you using `User::create()`?

Comment: Because I'm using the controller for registration. Should I create two different controllers for users and admins?

Comment: Because I find it rather difficult to give rules and permissions

Comment: All Users are users, they just have different Roles, Permissions, etc; defining an `Admin` class, alongside your existing `User` class is the wrong road; I've been down it before, and it causes more issues than it solves in Laravel. Regardless, check if `created_at` is `nullable` on your `Users` table, and check your `$timestamps` setting on the Model; there's likely a mismatch there.

Comment: Also, in the future, it's best to include specifically the code that is causing the error, and the full error message; you didn't tell us which code is triggering the error, and you cut off your error message before it shows the actual query, including the table being inserted into. Help us help you, please :)

Comment: Would you recommend to get rid of the admin table and find a way to give roles?

Comment: Yes, very much so, but that's not the issue you're facing here, so it's ultimately irrelevant and up to you which path you choose to go down. Laravel isn't really designed with multiple authentication Models in mind, so splitting that into separate Models instead of having a single, with multiple Roles (or whatever you want to call them) goes against the Framework instead of with it.